# Is it safe to move Apps like WhatsApp/MS teams stored in AppData/local folder from C: drive to D:?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, ssd

Like suppose if teams folder is  located in AppData folder. If I directly copy this folder to D drive and then use the application file in the folder to launch teams? Is this safe or I will break my windows or programs?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll break your programs.

However you can easily remedy this by creating a junction from the old location to your new location. When WhatsApp/Teams/Whatever looks in the old location, Windows will present the contents from the new location and the program will be none the wiser.

Assuming you take the contents of `C:\Users\Chaff\AppData\Local\LargeProgram` and move it to `D:\LargeProgram` then the following command will create a link between the two:

```
mklink /D "C:\Users\Chaff\AppData\Local\LargeProgram" "D:\LargeProgram"
```

Comment: And I want to ask is their any method that apps which do not let users choose download location will directly get installed on other drive instead of Appdata folder?

Comment: @UnscrewedChaff I'm not aware of anything but the best thing to do would be ask a new question. If a program doesn't allow me to move the location of a folder then I use the answer above to do so. Previously I used to use it for the SteamApps folder, although Steam now offer an option to configure an alternative location.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not delete folders in Appdata (Except some like Temp, CrashDumps or Browser temp folders).

If you delete/move the Teams or WhatsApp (or any other in that location) the app may stop working properly. Usually they contain many personal preferences and settings also some valuable data. SO removing them is not recommended.